# SustainSys-SAML2: claim transformation after sign-in

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Our team has successfully integrated **Sustainsys.Saml2**; great library, thank you!

We have a use-case where after a user signs-in and submits a form, a claim is added via an API call to the IdP; however, there is a minute delay before it is available. We need to be able to add this claim using SustainSys.Saml2 in the interim.

I know claim transformation is possible on sign-in using `AcsCommandResultCreated`; is there a way to perform claim transformation afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

This does not look really like a SAML2 related question. If I understand correctly what you want to do is to perform the SAML2 login completely, and then about a minute later add another claim to the authenticated session.

now you haven't tagged your question with what ASP.NET Version you use, so I assume Asp.Net Core. Then you would have to call SignInAsync again with an identity where you've added your additional claim.